# Angular 4 Child Route only works for numbers

Tags: angular

In my angular4 project I am trying to implement child routing.
and routes are

```
path: 'adminPanel', component: AdminPanelComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'setting1',
    component: Setting1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'setting2',
    component: Setting2Component
  },
]
```

and the links are provided in the AdminPanelComponent as,

```
 <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact : true}">
        <a [routerLink]="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact : true}">
        <a [routerLink]="setting1">setting1</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a [routerLink]="setting2">setting2</a>
    </li>
```

While running the code, Only the 'dashboard' component was working which is loaded by default when navigating to the parent 'adminPanel' since it is the default child for the parent.

But the other two links are not working when I click on them. But it is redirects to the desired component when I manually enter the url on the address bar.

After lots of tweaking I found out it's working when I changes the path values to numbers(here 'dashboard' to '1' , 'setting1' to '2' and 'setting3' to '3'), that is

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact : true}">
        <a [routerLink]="1">setting1</a>
    </li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact : true}">
        <a [routerLink]="2">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a [routerLink]="3">setting2</a>
    </li>
```

and in appRoutes as well

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't really understand  the question, but does the behavior improve if you use ` <a [routerLink]="/adminPanel/dashboard">`. It depends on what component contains the `routerLink`. I'm not able to derive that from the provided information.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer,I have edited my question and  Tried with the `<a [routerLink]="/adminPanel/dashboard">` and resulted with an error `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 
Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 1 in [/adminPanel/setting1] in ng:///AppModule/SidebarComponent.html@5:19 ("<li  [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact : true}">
                <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="/adminPanel/setting1">Dashboard</a>`

Comment: My bad, please remove `[]` around `routerLink`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Thanks , Now I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be

```
routerLink="setting1"
```

or

```
[routerLink]="['setting1']"
```

With the syntax you're using, `setting1` is an angular expression, and Angular is thus evaluating it as `theCurrentComponent.setting1`, i.e. the property named `setting1` of the current component.